# In Sketchup, how to create an exact angle within a box?

Tags: sketchup

I'm aware that this is a very basic question, but I can't seem to find the right terms to Google for. Any guidance would be appreciated.

What I want is a rectangular box with a triangular piece removed from it. The angle of the triangle being removed should be a specific angle.

What I've tried:

1. Draw a square
2. Pop that out into 3d
3. Draw a line on one of the six sides of the box
4. Push that line into the box using the Move tool

This gives me the shape I want, but without the exact control over the angle I need.

I've also tried using the Rotate tool on the line drawn in Step 3 above, and while that gives very interesting results, none of them is what I need.

My last resort will probably be a roundabout way of doing this, by building one half of the shape, and mirroring it - but that doesn't seem very proper either. Any suggestions?

Comment: And this has what to do with computers? Read the FAQ.

"What kind of questions can I ask here?

Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …

computer hardware
computer software"

Comment: I think you answered your own question when you quoted "computer software". SketchUp is "computer software", is it not? Considering that there are questions on Photoshop, InkScape, Visio and plenty of other drawing tools, it seemed SuperUser was an appropriate place to ask. If not - could you explain how/why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the protractor tool.

1. Draw a square.
2. Pop that out into 3d.
3. Use the protractor tool to draw a guide at a specific angle.
4. Draw line using guide.
5. Use push/pull to push out the not needed part.

If that doesn't help then watch all of [these videos](http://sketchup.google.com/training/videos/new_to_gsu.html). (I would suggest watching them even if my instructions helped.)

Comment: Awesome; exactly what I needed. I'll go watch the demo videos soon'ish (when this project is done).